# Django: custom middleware called twice

Tags: django, django-middleware

I have a custom middleware which is called twice for every request and I don't understand why.
This is my middleware:

```
class MyMiddleWare(object):

  def process_request(self, request):
    print 'FOO'
    return None
```

This is my middleware setting:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'MyMiddleware',
)
```

And this is the output in the console after homepage request:

```
[28/Jun/2013 19:48:26] FOO
[28/Jun/2013 19:48:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7468
[28/Jun/2013 19:48:27] FOO
```

I tried to comment out all the other middlewares and the problem is the same. What should I do?

ps: the described behavior is replicable in each view

**UPDATE**:

I tried to implement `process_view` rather than `process_request` and it is called once as expected... why?

**UPDATE 2**:

`process_response` is called twice like `process_request`

**UDATE 3**:

ooooh shiiiit! It's a request to favicon.ico (which I haven't defined myself)... who is calling this file?

Comment: It calls it once per request type. Is there an ajax request in the page ?

Comment: Sure it's only one request and you're probably not serving static files through `runserver` or something like that?

Comment: I'm using the development server without reload, and there is no ajax request... I tried to implement process_view rather than process_request and it is called once as expected... I don't understand :/

Comment: Do you have a redirect somewhere?

Comment: it's a request to the favicon!

Comment: Is your browser calling the file most likely :)

Comment: damned browser! ...I created a dummy favicon and now the middleware is called only once as expected :)

Comment: @daveoncode You should submit your own answer to this question for good housekeeping if you have the time to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that if you serve favicon.ico by defining it as django url (like the code below):

```
(r'^favicon\.ico$',
  'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to',
  {'url': settings.MEDIA_URL+'images/favicon.ico'}),
```

All your middleware get called twice: 1 time for the page you have requested + 1 time for the favicon (which is always called by the browser).
The solution is simple: don't use django urls to serve your vaficon, instead put something like:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'core/img/favicon.ico' %}" />
```

in the `<head>` of your base template!

Comment: This is not the only error source. jsi18n urls can be an issue too.

Answer (score 1):

Better solution is to add condition into your middlevare function that filters all serve functions.

```
if view_func.__name__ != 'serve':
```

Comment: What is `view_func`? Could you elaborate? There is no `view_func` in the `WSGIRequest` object we get on the middleware.