# Django middleware runs twice because of request to jsi18n

Tags: django, middleware, message

Running an extremely simple piece of middleware on django 3.2, I display notifications to users before every page loads. The code to do this looks like his:

```
from django.contrib import messages
class ChangeNotifierMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        
    def __call__(self, request):
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO,"test")
        response = self.get_response(request)
```

The issue however, is just like in [Django: custom middleware called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372743/django-custom-middleware-called-twice), this middleware is executed twice per request. This *only* happens in the django admin interface, and not because of requests to the favicon, but because of requests to /admin/jsi18n/. That makes the cause for this issue different (I did not specify any urls for jsi18n anywhere)

The result of all this is that on the front-end of my side, i get a single notification saying "test", as it should be. On the backend/admin interface, I get two notifications saying "test".
How can i make django middleware run only once before a page loads, is there a way to guarantee the code only runs once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like jsi18n is supposed to present the proper language translations for javascript activities.

You can skip adding your message for all urls containing "jsi18n" `if "jsi18n" not in request.path`

```
from django.contrib import messages
class ChangeNotifierMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        
    def __call__(self, request):
        if "jsi18n" not in request.path:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO,"test")
        response = self.get_response(request)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I came up with in the mean time as well, but i figured it would still be called when I install something that does perform additional request. If jsi18n gets called, are there other django features that, when enabled, perform additional requests? If so, i will have to add all those urls into a list and check against them manually.
Untill a more robust solution exists, I'll use exactly your idea, thanks again!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use Django's pre-built admin so I am unfamiliar with its features. Instead of trying to customize Django's pre-built admin, I tend to build my own custom back-end for applications.